# How do I find my Joomla database password?

Tags: password

I have Joomla website which I can login with administrator account. I also
can log into cpanel. But where can I find the Joomla database password? I don't know too much about phpMyAdmin and can't find the password in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2168037) your database password is not stored in the database.  It is stored in a configuration file.

For Joomla version 1.5

> It will be in the `configuration.php` normally on line 54 `'var $password =' 'yourpassword';`

For Joomla version 1.0 it will also be in `configuration.php` but you need to look for

> `$mosConfig_password = '';`